# Is there any way to prove another player's role?

Tags: town-of-salem

One of the great reasons I love Town of Salem (besides the Rap song by Minx/Dave) is how easy it is to be absolutely certain beyond any doubt that you know with great certainty who is a  where role is typically Serial Killer or Godfather, sometimes Jester or Executioner, maybe Witch.

I have played for a long time, and every-time a person gives absolutely perfect evidence for what they know, I can easily refute them using game mechanics.

An example, Once I was serial killer, 2 people visited me, 1 was prostitute and I don't recall the other. In a strange twist the other person whose role I forget, became targeted as the Serial Killer and was lynched. I survived to win the round.

This made me wonder, every rules or mechanic seems to be designed to prove a person is A but really only proves they are |A| by which is meant alignment can't be determined.

Is there any truth to this? Is it at all possible to prove concretely what a persons role is. Noting, in over 2k games I've played, I've never seen it happen with the exception of pure luck.

Answer (score 3):

## New Town of Salem Roles! :D

The existing answer gives quite a bit of information already. There have been some new roles so here are a few more specifications:

The [Consigliere](http://town-of-salem.wikia.com/wiki/Consigliere) ([Mafia Support](http://town-of-salem.wikia.com/wiki/Mafia_Support)) can retrieve the exact role of a player. However, if that person has been doused by an [Arsonist](http://town-of-salem.wikia.com/wiki/Arsonist), they will appear as an [Arsonist](http://town-of-salem.wikia.com/wiki/Arsonist) as well. If the player has been hexed by a [Hex Master](http://town-of-salem.wikia.com/wiki/Hex_Master), they will appear as a [Hex Master](http://town-of-salem.wikia.com/wiki/Hex_Master) as well.

The Sheriff can also tell if someone is part of the Coven (which is a new addition). The Investigator sees a list of possible roles of the player, and if they were framed, they will appear as Framer, Vampire, Jester, or Hex Master.

The [Mayor](http://town-of-salem.wikia.com/wiki/Mayor) can reveal themselves during the day which is absolute proof that the player is a [Mayor](http://town-of-salem.wikia.com/wiki/Mayor).

The [Witch](http://town-of-salem.wikia.com/wiki/Witch) and the [Coven Leader](http://town-of-salem.wikia.com/wiki/Coven_Leader) will see the exact role of the person they choose to control that night.

There are a few ways to find the role of a person. If a [Jailor](http://town-of-salem.wikia.com/wiki/Jailor) jails a player and is not visited by any players, then dies to a [Serial Killer](http://town-of-salem.wikia.com/wiki/Serial_Killer) or a [Werewolf](http://town-of-salem.wikia.com/wiki/Werewolf) (on a full moon night), then the jailed player is obviously that role. If a [Jailor](http://town-of-salem.wikia.com/wiki/Jailor) tries to execute a player or only one player voted guilty for a [Jester](http://town-of-salem.wikia.com/wiki/Jester) but they didn't die, then they have to be [Pestilence](http://town-of-salem.wikia.com/wiki/Pestilence), the only player with an Invincible defense.

Comment: So still no way to know for certain as every scenario has a "unless..."

Comment: @ydobonebi Yeah. Any way to determine a player's role for sure (other than hanging them or stabbing them at night and hoping they don't get Janitored) would be quite overpowered. I think Witch and Coven Leader get the exact role regardless of any influences, if I remember correctly.

Comment: So I guess the correct answer is then to hang them. Seems appropriate considering the central theme of the game.

Comment: @ydobonebi sure :P beware the jester though :D

Answer (score 2):

The [Consigliere](http://town-of-salem.wikia.com/wiki/Consigliere) is the only role that can find out for sure what another player's role is.  Unfortunately for the town, the Consigliere works for the Mafia.

The [Sheriff](http://town-of-salem.wikia.com/wiki/Sheriff) can tell for sure if a player is a Serial Killer or if they're a member of the Mafia (except the Godfather).  If a player is being framed, they will appear as suspicious, just like a Mafia member.

The [Investigator](http://town-of-salem.wikia.com/wiki/Investigator) can tell a small selection of roles that a player might be.  If a player is being framed, they will appear to be a Framer or Forger.

Comment: Sheriff can have false positives except serial killer, that's one down. Investigator has the problem i mentioned about alignment. Having a weapon, for example, could be town or mob. Never played consig, I'll have to check it.

Comment: @ydobonebi Consigliere always tells you the role.  However... Witch can change your target and Transporter can switch your target with a different person (I think you're informed about this).

Comment: Incidentally, Consigliere is one of the most powerful roles in the game.  Unless you're playing All Any, Consigliere is relatively rare.  This is different from Sheriff or Investigator which have 100% chance of getting both in Classic and 50% chance of getting at least one of them in Ranked (2/4 Investigative roles)... ignoring the Any role, which has a 1 / 27 or so chance of getting it.